# Can I get gml:id from GetFeature request

Tags: parameters, geoserver

I want to make a call to geoserver like `http://someurl:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&request=GetFeature --&someParameters...--` and get from geoserver just items I wrote in the parameters. For example I would like to have only gml:id of all features.

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use propertyName parameter:

propertyName=attribute1,attribute2

Example:

```
http://someurl:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=namespace:featuretype&featureID=feature&propertyName=id
```